# How do I check if a remote host is reachable at a specific port in C?

Tags: c, sockets

I am writing a C program to check whether remote host is responding to a specific port (In my case application is running on 9090 on remote side). Initially I tried
`nc -zv <host> <port>` using system() function call but unable to get the desired result. 
Now, I have created a non-blocking socket and using a connect() call to check the same. But its returning -1 and setting errno -115 (Operation in progress)
After searching on web I got the idea of using `select()` and `poll()`, but I am not able to get how to implement these. 
Any suggestion with sample program will be helpful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do exactly what you're doing, but in blocking mode.

Or else, do exactly wat you're doing and then add the socket FD to a writeFDs set and call `select().` If the FD shows up as writable, the connection has succeeded.

Don't forget to close the socket.

But I wonder why you're doing any of this. Just try to connect to whatever you need to connect to, at the moment you need to do so. Don't try to foretell whether it will succeed.

Comment: Is there any way where we can specify a timeout for the connect() call. I mean connect() will try for that many seconds in blocking mode

Comment: IIRC, the connect() timeout is a system-wide parameter on most OS, and assumes that the peer may be behind three satellite links and two modems, (ie, very long:).

Comment: @cbinder No. You would have to use `select()` for that. Note that you can only decrease the platform connect timeout, not increase it.

Comment: There is no way to specify a timeout for `connect()`. You must do the connection in non-blocking mode and use `select()` or `(e)poll()` to detect a timeout/result.

Comment: @EJP It was working fine till now, but now connect() in blocking mode takes about 20sec to return the status of host which is unreachable. I need to make it to return as soon as possible. Now when I  use select() and set the timeout as 0, then it is unable to detect the connection (returns 0), while on setting timeout (I tried 5sec) it works. What can be the safe value and is there any other way.

Answer (score 1):

What I understand is, you will only do a simple connect. Do should this in a *blockig mode*.
Here a example:

```
#include <netdb.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <sys/un.h>

in_addr_t in_build_addr(const char * p_server)
{
  in_addr_t addr = inet_addr(p_server);
  if(INADDR_NONE == addr) {
    struct hostent * server_info = gethostbyname(p_server);
    if(NULL == server_info) {
      return 0;
    }
    memcpy(&addr, server_info->h_addr_list[0], server_info->h_length);
  }
  return addr;
}

int check_connect(const char * p_server, in_port_t p_port) {
  int sock = socket(PF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);
  if(0 > sock) {
    return -1;
  }
  struct sockaddr_in addr = {
      .sin_family       = AF_INET,
      .sin_port         = htons(p_port),
      .sin_addr.s_addr  = in_build_addr(p_server)
    };
  if(0 != connect(sock, (struct sockaddr *)&addr, sizeof(addr))) {
    close(sock);
    return -2;
  }
  close(sock);
  return 0;
}
```

You can try to use the function _check_connect_. This function connects to a given server(ip or name) and port and close the socket immediately.